# Run Anaconda on second hard drive

Tags: anaconda

I already searched the Internet and SO but didnt find a case that was like mine, so here is my question:

I have my Windows installed on C: which is a SSD with ~20 GB space left. And I have a second hard drive D: where ~600 GB space are left.

Since both spyder and the Anaconda Prompt told me that there is not enough memory to save an array (~49 Million points), I tried to move Anaconda to D, where a lot of space is left (even though I do not know whether its enough).

Is there a way to do it? I reinstalled Anaconda after uninstalling it, but didnt work, the base directory is still C:/Users/Felix.

I really appreciate any help, Thank you!
Felix

EDIT: I now get a memory-error when I try to create the array using
    A = np.zeros(len(X),3))  (len(X) = 42 000 000)).
Guess thats a new error/problem because I obviously run out of RAM. Got to check if I have to use a subset of the data instead.

Comment: Why not just save it to the other drive by specifying the full path?

Comment: I tried this but it did not work out the way I did. How can I decide where to save the array?

Comment: Add the code you are using to save

Comment: Right now I don't have any real code where to save the array. Im just changing the direction in Spyder to my folder and create the array with numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a link between the D and C drives using the command mklink from a command prompt with administrative rights:

C:\Windows\system32>mklink /D C:\Users\Your-user-name\DATA D:\

DATA will represent your drive D.

Cheers!

Comment: Shouldn't that question be asked in [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?